# Pyinstaller doesn’t seem to work with Python 3.5.3

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I’m experiencing problems with Pyinstaller. I have code written in Python ***3.5.3*** that imports the `tkinter` module and I am trying to convert it to a .app bundle. However, when I run `pyinstaller -F -w -n appName —osx-bundle-identifier my.bundle.identifier myScript.py` in the dir containing `my script.py`, the resulting `dist/appName.app` does not launch.

---

I have tried:

- Using folder format instead of single-file

  I found nothing while trying to debug with this
- Removing Python ***2.x*** which uses `Tkinter` instead of `tkinter`

  This removes `pip` which renders Pyinstaller unusable
- Reinstalling Python with `brew install python3` as well as the Python website

  Pyinstaller does not support Python 3.6 and reinstalling Python 3.5.3 solves nothing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *I have tried: Using folder format instead of single-file*.  If you read "[If-Things-Go-Wrong](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong)" carefully you will find that the suggestion to use folder format is not as a suggestion to make it work, but it is a method to *debug* why it is not working.

Comment: That’s what I meant - looks like I wasn’t clear. Will edit the question.

Comment: Does the program give any feedback when it does not launch?

Comment: Nothing, although in my Dock (I’m using macOS Sierra) it looks like two apps are launching.

Comment: Have you tried to launch from the command line?

Comment: No, although I have tried running the executable created along with the .app.

Comment: If it is taking an exception during launch, I don't know where they would end up if not launched from the command line.  (Sorry, not a mac guy)